# Quick book integration for PHP Website

Tags: php, mysql, quickbooks-online

I am a PHP web developer. I have a project with a payment section. My client requested that I integrate this section with QuickBooks. I don't know anything about QuickBooks. Is there a framework for integrating QuickBooks? Also, how do I implement QuickBooks data into a PHP Mysql website? Thanks.

Comment: 1. http://quickbooks.intuit.com/ 2. That's really up to you and your requirements.

Comment: It's basically an accounting software. It it seems there has been a lot of discussion on their forms about the same issue. From that I found this: [QuickBooks PHP Devkit](http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/) that you might want to take a look it.

Comment: are you trying to integrate Quickbooks' payment gateway to accept payments or inteface with their quickbooks-online account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting remote PHP/Apache server to Quickbooks/Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953309/connecting-remote-php-apache-server-to-quickbooks-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Quickbooks is an accounting package. Plenty of people have linked into Quickbooks for custom applications over the years. Implementing it to a web based application will depend on your requirements.

Normally what is necessary is for the user to export the records to a CSV file or a QIF file and then you import it. If not some basic work has been done integrating Quickbooks with PHP which you can use. For example http://www.consolibyte.com/download.php?ID=5. There is also a great stackoverflow question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151216/php-quickbooks-integration-api. Like I said it depends on your requirements.